# Need to remove symbol for particular occurrence using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I need to remove + symbol for the particular occurrence using xsl.

My Input xml file is:

```
<term>
<image>Mediabakery_SPY0006138.jpg</image>
<name>Pramlintide</name>
<description>
<p>This medicine</p>
<ol>
<li>Use this medicine</li>
</ol>
<p>Write your thoughts here. . .</p>
</description>
<commentBox>false</commentBox>
</term>
```

XSL i used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="term">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description">
        "description": 
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        "<xsl:apply-templates/>" +
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol">
        "<xsl:copy-of select="." />" +
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="commentBox">
        "commentBox": "<xsl:apply-templates/>"
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

json Output i got as:

```
"description": 

"This medicine" +

"<ol><li>Use this medicine</li></ol>" +

"Write your thoughts here. . ." +
"commentBox": "false"
```

But i dont want the + symbol at the end as like below:

```
"description": 

"This medicine" +

"<ol><li>Use this medicine</li></ol>" +

"Write your thoughts here. . ." 
"commentBox": "false"
```

Please guide me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please rephrase your question

Comment: How i want to rephase @scanQR

Comment: If you want JSON output, you can't use "+" signs to concatenate strings. That might be valid Javascript, but it wouldn't be valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="description">
    "description": 
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
 "<xsl:apply-templates/>" <xsl:if test="following::text()[
     normalize-space()]
     [generate-id(ancestor::description)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::description)]">+</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ol">
    "<xsl:copy-of select="." />" <xsl:if test="following::text()[normalize-space()]">+</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
    "description": 


    "This medicine" +

    "<ol><li>Use this medicine</li></ol>" +

    "Write your thoughts here. . ."
```

Comment: This is not working @rudramuni, + symbol coming for all occurence

Comment: Last '+' symbol not required or all symbols not required?

Comment: last + symbol only @rudramuni, But i used this. But getting on all occurrence

Comment: I updated my code, check is that helpful? Which will suppress the last '+', if not followed by any text.

Comment: Sorry @Rudramuni, Its not working, Following the last para tag, another text element is coming. Is this affect due to this???

Comment: Within 'description' last para should not get the plus symbol? Then post the input XML with other text too.

Comment: @BoopathyS, last 'p' within 'description' should not get 'plus' symbol? is this condition is correct?

Comment: @BoopathyS, check now.